# Return newly inserted row without having to Submit to database

Tags: sql, linq

I need to find a way to get the newly insert row, without previously having to save to the database.

Is there a way? Or I need to keep the whole collection of row in a separated array?

Is this example I adding a row to the table tblConfig, but when I look back in the table the new row is not there.

```
 tblConfig Config = new tblConfig { ID = Guid.NewGuid(), Code ="new config code" };
 CTX.tblConfig.InsertOnSubmit(Config);
 var Data = from dd in CTX.tblConfig select dd;
 this.dataGridView1.DataSource = Data;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research , I'll do the work by attaching my LINQ query to a BindingSource object, witch will help me handle with insertion update and so.

Thanks for everyone, for your help :)

Hugo

Answer (score 0):

Could you add that manually like this?

```
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = CTX.tblConfig.Execute(MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```